# Can't Get Alias Name?

Tags: file, applescript, alias

I can't understand why this code does not work. `aItems` is an array with paths to aliases.

```
repeat with j in aItems
    set Aliasname to name of alias file j
    display dialog Aliasname as string
end repeat
```

I just want to get the name of each alias in the array, but it fails with:

> error number -1700 from alias file ... of startup disk to integer

When I hard code a path to an alias (literally the same path that is in `j`) it works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `set aItems to (every file of folder i whose kind is "Alias")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 suggestions. First I assume you got the aItems inside a Finder tell block of code. You also need to get the name from the Finder too, so first make sure the name line of code is inside a Finder tell block. Second, your list of aItems is a list of file references so when you ask for the name you don't need "alias file". Just ask for the name of j.

I hope that helps. Good luck.